Unable to get wireguard to work over lan, but works over hotspot
I have been using a home wireguard server for a year with no issue.
I recently changed ISP modem and reinstalled wireguard.
Now I can’t seem to connect to my wireguard server when I use an external LAN network.
It works when I use my 5g connection or a hotspot connected to my laptop.
But as soon as I connect to an external wifi network, I can't even get a handshake.
I have no idea what is going on.
I tried changing ports, changing ip address ranges and nothing seems to work.
I used pivpn to set it up.
Any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated.
Update:
I think I know what the problem is.
I tried it from my friends house that has ipv4 only, and i can connect! but when i go to my neighbour who has ipv4 and ipv6, it does not work.
Same for my cellular, it only has an ipv4 address.
my modem and wireguard used to support both ipv4 and ipv6, but now the isp has yet to activate my ipv6. could this be causing some weird issue???

Why did you reinstall wireguard if it was working?

it wasnt exactly working. i lost ipv6 and my isp has yet to activate it on this new modem. I have updated my question.

You shouldn't have had to uninstall Wireguard to remove IPv6 support. Is there anything helpful in the Wireguard logs?

https://dietpi.com/forum/t/unable-to-connect-to-my-dietpi-pivpn-wireguard-server-over-another-lan-network-hotspot-works-fine/20871 you can see the output from my logs here

i just discovered the i am unable to reach the ip address from my network to the external network. But i can reach both networks from my cellular network.
i think my ISP has separated the 1gbps and 5gbps internet plans.
